# Evaluate$\int_{S}\vec{F.d\vec{S}}$ where S is the surface of the plane $2x+y=4$ in the first octant cut off by the plane $z=4$

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

> **Question** Evaluate$\int_{S}\vec{F.d\vec{S}}$ where$\vec{F}$
>   = y$\hat{i}$ +$2x$$\hat{j}$-z$\hat{k}$ and S is the surface of
>   the plane $2x+y=4$ in the first octant cut off by the plane $z=4$

**My Approach** $\hat{n}=\frac{\nabla s}{\mid\nabla s\mid}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(2\hat{i}+\hat{j}\right)$
and $dS =\frac{dxdy}{\mid\hat{n.}\hat{j\mid}}=\sqrt{5} dxdy$

$\vec{F}\cdot\hat{n}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\left(x+y\right)$

$\vec{F}\cdot\hat{ndS}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\left(x+y\right)$$\sqrt{5}
dxdy=2\left(x+y\right)dxdy$

Now i can't decide the region of integral$\int_{S}2\left(x+y\right)dxdy$

Book's Approach my book uses this formula for $dS$

$$dS =\frac{dxdz}{\mid\hat{n.}\hat{j\mid}}=\sqrt{5} dxdz$$

Is my formula wrong? Or are both formulas correct?

If both formulas are correct then why my method is not giving the
right answer?

Comment: For surface integral in vector fields you need to specify the orientation of the plane right.

Comment: @user122049 i am not good at physics and i do not know what is orientation of vector fields and how it is connected to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to parametrise the surface. The surface can be parametrised in the following way: $\mathbf{r}(u,v)=\langle u, 4-2u, v \rangle$, where $u\in (0,2)$ and $v\in(0,4)$. Then, take partial derivatives $\mathbf{r}_u=\langle 1,-2,0\rangle$ and $\mathbf{r}_v=\langle 0, 0, 1\rangle$; consequently, $\mathbf{r}_u\times\mathbf{r}_v=\langle -2, -1, 0\rangle$. This will give you one choice of normal vector $\mathbf{n}$, but whether this is the correct orientation, it is dependent on the question(the other being $-\mathbf{n}$). That is why I ask for the correct orientation.

We compute the surface integral in the following way: $\int_S\mathbf{F} \mathrm{d}S=\iint_D\mathbf{F}\cdot(\mathbf{r}_u\times\mathbf{r}_v)\mathrm{d}A$, where $D$ is comprised of all the $(u,v)$ in domain. Here, the equation gives $\iint_D\langle 4-2u,2u,-v\rangle\cdot\langle -2, -1, 0\rangle\mathrm{d}A=\int_0^4\int_0^2(-8+2u)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v=-48$

Comment: Thanks brother your approach is very much helpful for the many other problems as well.i  had seen this method on the internet,but it was not given in my book ,but from now i will always use this method

Comment: @Mohan Sharma , I solved this and got +48 .Please tell me the correct answer .

Comment: @Mohan please tell me the answer so that i can correct my approach .

Comment: @Abhishek Hi, since the orientation of the surface is not given, both $+48$ and $-48$ are correct answers.